# Onclick button isnt working in vue.js in option tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im trying to get the item properties that is being clicked in the option button

This is my code

```
                                        <select @click="populate" class="form-control" tabindex="12">
                                            <option disabled value="" selected="selected">Select one</option>
                                            <option v-for="(payment, index) in paymentsSelect" @click="pop(payment)" 
                                                    :key="index" 
                                                    :value="payment.id">{{ payment.name }}
                                            </option>
                                        </select>
```

this is my data

```
        selectedPayment: '',
        paymentsSelect: [],
```

these are my methods

```
pop(payment){
        console.log(payment)
    },
    populate(){
        var self = this

        this.$http.get(this.$backendUrl + 'subjects/payment_method')
        .then(function(response) {
            self.paymentsSelect = response.data.data
        })
        .catch(function() {})
    },
```

Comment: why don't you add the event on the change event of the select control?

Comment: I don't know, how to get the object that is being clicked even with on change,

Comment: The option tag doesn't have a click event - as Nicolas said, you'll have to use the events on the select

Comment: explanation here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

Comment: Thanks both of you, you helped me a lot. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add event, just bind the select input to a data property using `v-model` like :

```
 <select v-model="selectedPayment" class="form-control" tabindex="12">
    <option disabled value="" selected="selected">Select one</option>
      <option 
           v-for="(payment, index) in paymentsSelect"  
            :key="index" 
            :value="payment">
         {{ payment.name }}
       </option>
</select>
```

`selectedPayment` changes when you select an option then use it in your script like `this.selectedPayment`